# How do I build an exchange on top of ERC721?

Tags: erc-721, exchanges

I want to build an exchange that allows users to list existing ERC721 tokens. The problem is that I have looked at Wyvern and don't really understand it. I've seen smaller protocols (such as zora) but they must be minted to their own collection. How do I build an exchange where already existing ERC721s can be listed?

Comment: Your question is too broad. A solution is a contract that accepts tokens in consignment and when someone purchases a token the price minus a fee is sent to the creator and the token transferred to the buyer.

Comment: @Ismael  ok. This makes sense. It seems like Wyvern has a lot of other contracts though, why would you need so much extra functionality? The solution you pointed out requires 1-2 contracts max

Comment: It was just a possible implementation. If you want to support other features the contracts will grow in complexity. I haven't used Wyvern so I can't say what's the difference.